# scala won't find 'should' function

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have this code for the test:

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.Matchers

class TestSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "something" should "be something else" in {
    "test" should be ("test")
  }
}
```

However i get this error:

```
Error:(21, 12) overloaded method value should with alternatives:
  (resultOfAfterWordApplication: org.scalatest.verb.ResultOfAfterWordApplication)(implicit fun: (String, String, org.scalatest.verb.ResultOfAfterWordApplication) => Unit)Unit <and>
  (right: => Unit)(implicit fun: org.scalatest.verb.StringVerbBlockRegistration)Unit <and>
  (right: org.scalatest.verb.BehaveWord)(implicit fun: String => org.scalatest.verb.BehaveWord)org.scalatest.verb.BehaveWord <and>
  (right: String)(implicit fun: (String, String, String) => org.scalatest.verb.ResultOfStringPassedToVerb)org.scalatest.verb.ResultOfStringPassedToVerb
 cannot be applied to (org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher[Any])
    "test" should be ("test")
           ^
```

I am taking the code straight from their website and installed ScalaTest through the maven descriptor org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10.0:2.0.M5 which seems to be latest right now

Comment: Well, to be honest, i worded that wrong, edited question to be more correct.

Comment: Changing `import org.scalatest.FlatSpec` to `import org.scalatest._` did not change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers

class TestSpec extends FlatSpec with ShouldMatchers
```